# Two Body/text areas for a multilingual site

Tags: i18n-l10n

When creating a new node, I want 2 body text areas, each one for one language (one in English, and one in German ).

How can I have 2 body areas when create a node?

Comment: Since you seem to just want to show one language at time, is there any reason you could not create a node in German, and a node in English. With core modules, showing one of those nodes basing on the language set from the user or the site is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the content type that you are using or create a new one and add another field to it.

Comment: Yes but I want one field to appear when english are selected and the other one when the german language is selected.So I want eah field for each language.

Comment: Ok, if you want to write out two fields in two different languages I would suggest a view that displays your ct using an exposed filter. Possibly use [conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) to display one or the other dependent on a form item state (or write your own using [`#states`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states)). This is all assuming that using Drupals [t()](https://www.drupal.org/node/1844980) is not sufficient. A little more info about your use case would help us help you.